# Background color of top header image

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am making react native expo app. I have header where i put image as a background. And i want to put background color on this image, but when i write background color, it is not working. How i can put background color on image in header
Code:

```html
  navigationOptions: {
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerBackground: (
              <Image
              source = {{ uri: "http://rapprogtrain.com/img/new/computer-2788918_1280.jpg" }}
                style={{resizeMode:'cover',    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                    height:250, backgroundColor:'#1e1e21' }}
              />
        ),
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
 navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {{ backgroundColor:'#1e1e21' }}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toolbar. it's can change backgroundcolor .

example.js

```js
import {ToolbarAndroid} from "react-native"
render: function() {
  return (
    <ToolbarAndroid
      style={{backgroundColor:'#1e1e21'}}
      logo={require('./app_logo.png')}
      title="AwesomeApp"
      actions={[{title: 'Settings', icon: require('./icon_settings.png'), show: 'always'}]}
      onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected} />
  )
},
onActionSelected: function(position) {
  if (position === 0) { // index of 'Settings'
    showSettings();
  }
}
```